# In what way can the Riemannian curvature be regarded as a two-form with values in $\mathfrak{hol}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, holonomy

Denote $G:=Hol(g) \subset SO(n)$ and $\mathfrak{g}:=\mathfrak{hol}{g} \subset \mathfrak{so}(n)$.
The Levi-Civita connection $A \in \Omega^1(GL(M), \mathfrak{gl}(n))$ reduces to a connection $\hat{A} \in \Omega^1(G(M), \mathfrak{g})$.

The curvatures of $A$ and $\hat{A}$ are 2-forms in the following spaces: $F_A \in \Omega^2(GL(M),\mathfrak{gl}(n))$, $F_\hat{A} \in \Omega^2(G(M), \mathfrak{g})$.
Alternatively, we can view $F_A$ (or $F_\hat{A}$) as a curvature endomorphism on the associated fiber bundle $GL(M) \times \mathbb{R}^n \simeq G(M) \times \mathbb{R}^n \simeq TM$.
I.e. $R \in \Gamma ( \Lambda^2T^*M \otimes End(TM,TM))$.

Now, in what way is $\mathfrak{g} \subset End(TM,TM))$ and why does $\nabla$ take values in $\mathfrak{g}$?

It does not seem too far fetched, because $\hat{A}$ takes values in $\mathfrak{g}$, but I do not know how to make this precise.

Comment: You say "we can view $A$ as a curvature endomorphism". I dont think so : the curvature is obtained first by computing the derivative of $A$ and then projecting on $M$. Furthermore, the Levi-Civita connexion is here a 1-form on $O(M)$ with values in $\cal G $, where $O(n)$ is the bundle of orthonormal frames.

Comment: You are right. The correspondence is, in short, $A \leftrightarrow \nabla$ and $F_A \leftrightarrow R$, and not $A \leftrightarrow R$, as I claimed. I edited that in my question. The question still lacks context, so I will probably delete it in the next days.